# Disable Scrolling when angular-material select is open

Tags: angular-material2

By default the select-dropwon of angular-material  will allow the page to scroll and reposition itself accordingly.

On the original page of the material-documentation the select-dropdown shows a differetn behaviour: it blocks scrolling when openend:

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

How can I achieve this behaviour? I did not find any options or switch to disable scrolling when the select is clicked

EDIT:
I did find that there is a thing called "mat-select-scroll-strategy", but it is not documented anywhere. Can anybody give me a hint how to use this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since the mat-select component injects a strategy through DI, you can provide an alternative in your component (or at the module level if you wish).

```
import { MAT_SELECT_SCROLL_STRATEGY } from '@angular/material';
import { Overlay, BlockScrollStrategy } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

export function scrollFactory(overlay: Overlay): () => BlockScrollStrategy {
  return () => overlay.scrollStrategies.block();
}

// ...

providers: [
  { provide: MAT_SELECT_SCROLL_STRATEGY, useFactory: scrollFactory, deps: [Overlay] }
]
```

--

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-n3vcb1?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand the question and the answer but I want the dropdown option to never show a scroll no matter how long the option list is. Your solution doesn't do that. Could you clarify?

Comment: This question is concerning the page scroll _behind_ the select overlay. You can probably achieve what you need via the `overflow` CSS property.

Comment: @Will Howell Yes. I noticed this on angular.io. The weird thing is that the code provided in your answer, is not used in the angular.io examples 'code' panel. In fact there is no mention of MAT_SELECT_SCROLL_STRATEGY anywhere? I am just wondering whether on angular.io, this strategy is added to the app.module.ts file? I would prefer to be able to use this strategy globally, so that I only have to use it once. And, also, the page does scroll, it is just that the select menu repositions itself, so that it's position is maintained relative to its parent.

Comment: And, I have no idea why this is not the default behaviour of the mat-select? It is pretty unnatural to have a mat-select with a 'fixed' position. It would be easier, if Angular could just provide an additional mat-select input called something like '[maintainRelativePosition]="true/false"'

Comment: @Will Howell I have found out that none of these strategies work, if the mat-select is in a scrollable container element. They only seem to work inside a scrolling body. I was wondering whether you knew a way of resolving this issue. I want to use: RepositionScrollStrategy(this._scrollDispatcher, this._viewportRuler, this._ngZone, config), but I have no idea what the 4 arguments represent. I am hoping one of them represents a reference to the scroll container?

Comment: @CharlesRobertson I realize I'm several days late on this, but could you provide a minimum stackblitz of what your issue is? I haven't used material2 in a while but I still might be able to help!

Comment: @Will Howell I found out what the issue is. The scroll strategy only works by default on the body. If a child container requires scroll strategy, it is necessary to add the following input to that container: cdkScrollable. In the end, I didn't like the effect, because Material keeps select list above every other z-index. In the end, I created my own scrolll strategy, where the select list fades out, if a user starts scrolling its container.

Comment: @Will Howell this does not seem to be working for autocomplete with a different scroll container than body. I forked your stackblitz example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta12-pf5aup
I had to add cdkScrollable to the scroll container, then reposition and close do work but block does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Your stackbliz has an Error in theme.scss
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'write$1' on null

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue and i find the solution in *GitHub Response*
[autocomplete does not stick when scrolling](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10079)

So, i rewrite the response to make it useful response and easiest way to solve problem.

*1. First*, we need to add an `id` to our input **#autoCompleteInput**

```
<input matInput #autoCompleteInput [formControl]="filter [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

*2. Second*, we need to add in our component a `ViewChild` to have autoComplete as a variable

```
@ViewChild('autoCompleteInput', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger })
autoComplete!: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

*3. Third*, we need a scrolling event

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scrollEvent, true);
}
```

*4. Fourth and Finally*, we need a function in our component

```
scrollEvent = (): void => {
    if (this.autoComplete.panelOpen)
        this.autoComplete.updatePosition();
};
```