# mat-select: how to show all options without scrolling?

Tags: angular, sass

I'd like to disable the scrollbar when I have more than 5 options:

[image]

**Code:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-size?file=app/select-overview-example.html

**Demo:**

https://angular-select-size.stackblitz.io

I tried to use the "size" option, however I found that is not available:

```
<mat-option ng-size=8 *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
  {{food.viewValue}}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Scrolling when angular-material select is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888635/disable-scrolling-when-angular-material-select-is-open)

Answer (score 4):

Previous answers did not work directly for me and I needed `::ng-deep` (`/deep/` to be deprecated see - [What do /deep/ and ::shadow mean in a CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25609678/what-do-deep-and-shadow-mean-in-a-css-selector]))

i.e.

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
  max-height: none !important;
}
```

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
  max-height: 400px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//add this code to you styles.css

   ::ng-deep .mat-select-panel{
       max-height: none!important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the height of the select panel.

Add this code to your `styles.css`

```
.mat-select-panel {
  max-height: 400px !important;
}
```

The number `400px` is a random one. If your data are too many you must add a bigger number.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-size-8vkutp

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to you global styles.css

```
.my-select.mat-select-panel{
  max-height: none!important;
}
```

Include panelClass="my-select" property in the mat-select component.

Comment: Should be marked as the correct answer if you want to have max-height for a specific mat-select

Answer (score 1):

Solution if you don't want to use `!important`.
The panel takes the id of the `mat-select` with `-panel` suffix :

```html
<mat-select id="dumb-id"
...
```

```css
::ng-deep #dumb-id-panel {
  max-height: none;
}
```